# How To Save Datetime With PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to execute following PDO statement

```
"INSERT INTO `vk_posts` (`date`, `text`) VALUES (':date', ':text')"
```

Where :date is datetime column

```
$post["date"] = 1381850707;
$stm->execute(array(
        "text" => $post["text"]
        ,"date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $post["date"])
    ));
```

I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: ':date' for column 'date' at row 1
```

Comment: One of the benefits of PDO is that it is relatively database neutral. the delimiters around the table and column names here are MySQL only, and completely unnecessary. You can readily use: `INSERT INTO vk_posts (date,text) VALUES (:date, :text)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The placeholder names should not be quoted. Remove the quotes around `:date` and `:text`, so it becomes:

```
"INSERT INTO `vk_posts` (`date`, `text`) VALUES (:date, :text)"
```

Comment: The `:` prefix in the parameter array is optional.

Comment: By way of explanation, quotes are only necessary when creating a new string literal. In a prepared statement, the place holders are just place holders, and are not of themselves string literals. When it comes to populating the placeholders, you might put string literals into the array. Its the same logic behind why we don’t put quotes around string variables.